# Can C++20 concepts be redeclared or not?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

This one's rather straightforward: according to the [cppreference article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), concepts can be redeclared no problem:

[image: image of cppreference saying it can be redeclared]

So I figured alright, cool, I don't have to worry about redeclaring my concept for creating "printable enums"; I can declare the concept in both my logging header and my common types header, so I only have to include what's needed:

```cpp
// common types header
#include <enum_traits.hpp>

template<typename E>
concept PrintableEnum = requires(E& e) { {enum_traits<E>::toString(e)} -> std::same_as<const char*>; };

template<PrintableEnum T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& o)
{
   os << enum_traits<T>::toString(o);
   return os;
}

// logging header

template<typename T>
concept PrintableEnum = requires(T& e) { {enum_traits<T>::toString(e)} -> std::same_as<const char*>; };

template<PrintableEnum T>
plog::Record& operator<<(plog::Record& rec, const T& o) 
{
   rec << enum_traits<T>::toString(o);
   return rec;
}
```

(Ignore that the ostream overload could probably cover the plog record overload for the moment; that's probably how I'm gonna work around the problem, but I'm curious about this first.)

So when I try to compile this, MSVC throws a fit for every file both headers are included in (which one it points to as the error changes based on include order):

```sh
[build] commontypes.hpp(25): error C7571: 'PrintableEnum': variable template has already been initialized
[build] logging.hpp(162): note: see declaration of 'PrintableEnum'
```

Also note, doing what cppreference does in that screenshot and duplicating the PrintableEnum declaration right under the first one in one of the files is the same problem.

So, is cppreference *wrong* here? Does the standard not actually say anything about redeclarations? (I'm not actually sure where the official c++ standard is kept if not on cppreference...) Do I need to worry about redefinitions of concepts like anything else in C++?

Or is MSVC wrong here? (Not that I can do much about MSVC...) Searching the error message only got me stuff about other redeclarations, like classes and variables. Apparently "concept" is not very SEO-friendly.

Comment: I think you are trying to do something different from the sample on cppreference. It says you can redeclare a constrained declaration. You are trying to redefine a concept already declared. I don't see why you are not using an header where you declare your concept and then include it in both your other headers.

Comment: @Federico - Making an entirely new header file simply to hold the concept that's shared between two other header files seems a bit like overkill. Like I said in the question, I'm just gonna remove the one specifically for plog Records, since plog can work just with ostream operators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This one's rather straightforward: according to the cppreference article, concepts can be redeclared no problem:

No, it doesn't say that. This snippet:

```cpp
template<Incrementable T>
void f(T) requires Decrementable<T>;
 
template<Incrementable T>
void f(T) requires Decrementable<T>; // OK, redeclaration
```

Doesn't redeclare a concept. It doesn't even *declare* a concept. What it's showing is declaring the same *function template*, twice. That function template is constrained (with both `Incrementable` and `Decrementable`), but it is still a function template.

You cannot redeclare a concept.

One reason is that you can't just *declare* a concept, you always also *define* it. You can't just write:

```cpp
template <class T> concept C;
```

in the same way that you can write:

```cpp
template <class T> void f();
```

`f` here just a declaration of a function template, and I can add another declaration of it. But only one definition. This is ill-formed:

```cpp
template <class T> void f() { }
template <class T> void f() { }
```

in the same way that this is ill-formed:

```cpp
template <class T> concept C = true;
template <class T> concept C = true;
```

There can only be one definition.

Comment: So basically I'm an idiot and completely missed something blindingly obvious. What was repeated was a function's forward declaration, and not the definition of the concept. Thanks for spelling it out for me.